# Why does the theta function appear in the study of complex tori?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, theta-functions

Let $L$ be a lattice and $X = \mathbb{C}/L$ a complex tori.

To obtain a meromorphic function $f$ on $X$, it is standard to consider ratios of products of (translated) theta-functions, and in fact, any meromorphic function on $X$ has this form.

**Question.** Why do theta functions appear in this context? I do not quite understand the intuition of using them here in the first place.

Comment: $\theta(z,\tau)$ is $1$-periodic, it is close to be $\tau$-periodic, and its zeros are simple at $(\tau+1)/2 + \Bbb{Z}+\tau \Bbb{Z}$

Comment: The origin of theta functions is due to Jacobi who tried to find infinite product representations for his elliptic function. The lattice and tori came later and it is difficult to see how theta functions pop out from them. The way (via complex analysis) to get them is using double periodic nature of elliptic functions and applying Fourier analysis (based on periodic nature).